# can I make an alphabetical Ordered List starting at B instead of A

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to make a summary of locations with google maps API. On the map there are letters corresponding to the waypoints, I have a separate `<div>` with all the route information.

Right now I have it set as an `<ul>`, I want to make it an `<ol>` with letters. However, since the starting location isn't included in the route information and it has a marker with A on the map my route information needs to start with B.

Is there a way to do this?

I have tried making a list item before the rest with `display: none`.

I tried using the `start` attribute.

I tried using the `value` attribute in combination with a JavaScript array.

```
<ol id="sortable" class="directions-panel list-container list" type="A">
  <li style="display:none;"></li>
</ol>
```

```
<ol id="sortable" class="directions-panel list-container list" type="A" start="B"></ol>
```

```
<ol id="sortable" class="directions-panel list-container list" type="A">
  <li value="B"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Use start `start=2` instead of `start="B"`

Comment: this works! thanks! @Walk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close - [the `start` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#Attributes) accepts a *number* as the starting position, regardless if the list displays letters or numbers. All you need is `start="2"`:

```html
<ol id="sortable" class="directions-panel list-container list" type="A" start="2">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ol>
```